# Styling adjacent groups of like classes as a block via CSS? Obvious or impossible?

Tags: css

I have an interesting problem, consider this HTML:

```
<div class="foo">Hello</div>
<div class="foo">World</div>

<div class="bar">Hotel</div>
<div class="bar">Romeo</div>
<div class="bar">Foxtrot</div>

<div class="foo">Ford</div>
<div class="foo">Prefect</div>
```

This content is dynamically generated and I never know when the class is going to flip.  Is there a pure CSS way of styling groups of elements of a class?  For example, I want each adjacent group of class "foo" to be bold and have a specific margin while each adjacent group of class "bar" I want to be red in color.

```
**Hello**
**World**

Hotel
Romeo
Foxtrot

**Ford**
**Prefect**
```

Help me stackoverflow, you're my only hope!

Comment: Not sure I'm following. What does the "adjacent" part have to do with anything? What's wrong with `.foo{font-weight:800;} .bar{color:red;}`?

Comment: The font weight and color are easy, but the margin is what I really need. I want to group each set of elements with class "foo" separately and style them with a common set of properties.  Basically, I want each group of "foo" and "bars" to alternate bold/normal and a margin separating each group.  The problem is these are being fed dynamically and in no predictable order and I never know if the next one is "foo" or "bar".  So I may get 10 "foo"'s then one "bar" and I want each set to be together with a top/bottom margin while maintaining their natural order.

Comment: Style each set of "foo" and "bars" as blocks (without a wrapper and avoiding javascript).

Comment: You can't style a group of elements, you can only style elements. There was some proposal to be able to wrap elements inside an anonymous pseudo-element and be able to style it, but it wasn't specced nor implemented.

Comment: nvioli had a trivial and perfect solution, kudos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
.foo + .bar,
.bar + .foo{
  margin-top:10px;
}
```

This will add 10px of margin every time a `.bar` div follows a `.foo` div, or vice versa.

```css
.foo + .bar,
.bar + .foo {
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-top: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">Hello</div>
<div class="foo">World</div>

<div class="bar">Hotel</div>
<div class="bar">Romeo</div>
<div class="bar">Foxtrot</div>

<div class="foo">Ford</div>
<div class="foo">Prefect</div>
```

Comment: Good answer!  Couldn't resist adding a separator... Feel free to delete it if you want :-)